# The filter pattern in .gitignore doesn't act as intended

Tags: git

I have added a filter pattern in .gitignore

It works for most of the files I don't want to put in git, but there are still 4 files that are not filtered though they should be.

- the only pattern in .gitignore is: `*./metadata/*`

but in the list of files that are ready to stage (in GitExtension):

- java_workspace/.metadata/.mylyn/.tasks.xml.zip
- java_workspace/.metadata/.mylyn/tasks.xmlzip
- java_workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.prefs
- java_workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/workingsets.xml

What's wrong in my .gitignore file ?

Comment: Can you give us the output of git status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern in `.gitignore` doesn't consider files that are under version control. I.e., I've got a bunch of images under `git`, most are source that is processed into PNG, but a few are PNGs from elsewhere. My `.gitignore` has `*.png`, but the files I placed explicitly under version control aren't ignored, and that's how I'd like things to be.

If the offending files shouldn't be under version control, just `git rm` them. If they appear again, `git` will ignore them.